# How to get which letter/word focused by the SQL LIKE operator

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to making a search engine something like this:
**PHP**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$text = $_GET['text'];
$select = $_GET['select'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM papers WHERE {$select} LIKE '%{$text}%' ORDER BY ID DESC, {$select} ASC LIMIT 15";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . $conn->error);
}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">
        <span class="id">
            <?php echo $row["ID"] ?>.
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <span class="name">
            <?php echo $row["Name"] ?>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span class="ch">
            CH: <?php echo $row["ch"] ?>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span class="en">
            EN: <?php echo $row["en"] ?>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<?php
}
} else {
    echo '<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Not Found!<li>';
}
?>
```

**JS**

```
$('#search,#select').change(search);
$('#search').keyup(search);
function search() {
    var text = $('#search').val();
    var select = $('#select').val();
    var tl = $('#search').val().length
        tl == 0 ? $('#searchre').hide('slow') : $('#searchre').show('slow');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'search.php',
        data: {
            'text': text,
            'select': select
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (html) {
            $('#searchre').html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

It's working fine.But I am trying to highlight the input word on the result. How can I do this? And one more problem is that when I type **U** it's showing first **PUT** when have a word with first letter **U** like **umbrella**. How can I solve this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html
which more closely resembles an actual search and would probably help your result order.

Answer (score 0):

to highlight keyword you may use something like

```
$('#searchre').html(html.replace(text, '<div class="keyword">' +keyword + '</div>'));
```

and add some CSS to the class `.keyword'

```
.keyword{
   color:yellow;
}
```

and to get the result with the order of keyword position you can use php sort function something like below

```
            <?php
        require_once 'config.php';
        $text = isset($_GET['text']) ? $_GET['text'] : '';
        $select = isset($_GET['select']) ? $_GET['select'] : '';

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM papers WHERE {$select} LIKE '%{$text}%' ORDER BY ID DESC, {$select} ASC LIMIT 15";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if (!$result) trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . $conn->error);

        $resultArray = [];

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resultArray[] = $row;
        }

        usort($resultArray, function ($a, $b) {
            //here I assume the column name to 'name' you may need to change it
            return (strpos($a['name'], $text) < strpos($b['name'], $text)) ? -1 : 1;
        });

        if ($resultArray) {
            foreach ($resultArray as $row) { ?>
                // output data of each row
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                    <div class="row align-items-start">
                        <div class="col">
                <span class="id">
                    <?php echo $row["ID"] ?>.
                </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                <span class="name">
                    <?php echo $row["Name"] ?>
                </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span class="ch">
                    CH: <?php echo $row["ch"] ?>
                </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span class="en">
                    EN: <?php echo $row["en"] ?>
                </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
        } else {
            echo '<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Not Found!<li>';
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: It's showing PHP error Warning:  usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in G:\XAMPP\htdocs\pro-1\search.php on line 16

Comment: you should pass first parameter array of the query result in order to get it work

Comment: save the query result in an array first `while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
    $new_array[] = $row; // Inside while loop
}` and pass that array to usort

Comment: I am really new in PHP.I can't manage this, can you edit your answer with full details ?

Comment: I have updated answer I have not checked myself anyway give it a try